# Magento 1.7 Custom Module Can Rewrite Classes But Not Insert Block

Tags: magento, module, url-rewriting, overriding

I have created a custom module in magento 1.7.0.2 that does two things. Ok, at the moment it does one thing, thats why I am here.

What it does do successfully is sort my grouped products' associated products by sku.

However, I am also trying to override a template file and it is not working. I have 10 hours non-stop into this.

I want to replace catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml with groupedproductfilter/product/view/type/grouped.phtml.

etc/modules/Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Lightsnholsters/GroupedProductFilter/etc/config.xml

```
<config> 

  <modules>
    <Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <models>     
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <product_type_grouped>Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter_Model_Product_Type_Grouped</product_type_grouped><!-- sort grouped products by sku -->
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>        
    </models>

    <helpers>
      <groupedproductfilter>
        <class>Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter_Helper</class>
      </groupedproductfilter>
    </helpers>  

    <blocks>
      <groupedproductfilter>
        <class>Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter_Block</class>
      </groupedproductfilter>   
    </blocks>   
  </global>

  <frontend>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <groupedproductfilter>
          <file>groupedproductfilter.xml</file>
        </groupedproductfilter>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>

</config>
```

layout/groupedproductfilter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <catalog_product_view>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
      <reference name="product.info">
        <remove name="product.info.grouped"/>
        <block type="groupedproductfilter/product_view_type_grouped" name="grouped" as="product_type_data" template="groupedproductfilter/product/view/type/grouped.phtml"/> 
      </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped> 
  </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

layout/groupedproductfilter.xml successfully removes product.info.grouped but the block I am replacing it with from groupedproductfilter/product/view/type/grouped.phtml simply will not show up under any circumstances. All I have it set to do right now is echo 'test' just so I can see that it shows up and then I will take it from there.

I have other modules that I have purchased that replace template files in the same manner but the one I am doing doesnt work.

Thank you very much for getting me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergei Guk, thanks for trying to help me out. I finally got it working. In my layout xml file I changed it to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
    <reference name="product.info">
      <remove name="product.info.grouped"/>
      <block type="groupedproductfilter/product_view_type_grouped" name="grouped" as="product_type_data" template="groupedproductfilter/product/view/type/grouped.phtml"/>
    </reference>
  </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</layout>
```

It now ignores catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml and uses groupedproductfilter/product/view/type/grouped.phtml instead.

Comment: If Sergei helped you a significant amount, you might want to upvote his answer and accept yours so we know this question already has a solution.

Comment: Seth, as kind as he was was, his answer did not work out for me and I found my own solution.

Comment: i also did upvote him. I have also purchased code from his company prestashop before.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to setTemplate?

If you do something like this

```
<layout>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
        <reference name="product.info.grouped">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>groupedproductfilter/product/view/type/grouped.phtml</template>
                </action>
        </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</layout>
```

The result would be as expected, product info block will be rewrited
[image: product info]

If you want rewrite the whole page, try this

```
<layout>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
        <reference name="product.info">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>groupedproductfilter/product/view/type/grouped.phtml</template>
                </action>
        </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</layout>
```

You will get the whole product page rewrited
[image: whole page]

Comment: Yes. Many of my searches had the same answer. However, it does not work for me. In a module that I use for my images, they use the exact method I want to use and it works perfectly in their module. I tried to mimic it but its not working for me either.
        <reference name="product.info">
            <remove name="product.info.media" />
            <block type="fancyzoom/media" name="morningtime.fancyzoom" as="media" template="morningtime/fancyzoom/media.phtml"/>
        </reference>

Theirs looks like this

Comment: I am thinking that I have the block type wrong but the truth is that I dont really know the naming conventions well, thats probably where my problem is.

Comment: I've updated my answer, with screenshots (recreated your extension)

Comment: thank for helping me make some progress. That method finally echoed out my hello world text. Upon further testing though, I could not invoke my methods using $this. $this should refer to my class Lightsnholsters_GroupedProductFilter_Block_Product_View_Type_Grouped extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Grouped.

Comment: Any idea how to accomplish both? I know it can be done because my site contains modules that can do so but its making me crazy. thanks